# Iptables Forwarding problem

Tags: iptables, linux, linux-networking

I had initally asked question about sertting up my linux box for natting for my home network and was given suggestions in the thread [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/233427/iptables-forwarding-masquerading). Did not want to clutter the old question so starting a new one here.

based on the earlier suggestions, i have come up with the following rules ...

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:48]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [12:860]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3:228]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT DROP [3:228]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

If you notice, i do have the proper MASQURADING rule and the proper FORWARD filter rule as well.
However i am facing 2 problems

1. On the linux box itself DNS resolving is not working
2. the lan clients connected to the linux box, are still not able to get to internet. when i ping something from them, i see the DROP count in iptables INPUT rule increasing.

now my question is, when i am pinging something from the lan client, how come it is being matched by the input chain ?! should it be in the forward chain ?

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 20 packets, 2314 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   99  9891 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
  122  9092 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
```

Thanks    ankit

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to work out the DNS problems. the only thing not working right now is the forwarding.

These are the rules i have right now

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 1158 packets, 89867 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
   59  5448 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
  643 47995 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:domain dpts:1024:65535
   54  7811 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
 4168  273K ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1806  156K ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
   91 19451 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            udp spts:1024:65535 dpt:domain
10973  638K LOG_DROP   all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   80  6734 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 6327 2445K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOG_DROP (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
10973  638K LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `[IPTABLES DROP] :'
10973  638K DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

1. As you can see i have created a LOG_DROP rule to log all the dropped packets
2. on one of my LAN clients i am pinging google, but get no reply

this is what i see in the message log

```
Feb 12 17:15:15 LINUX-GATEWAY kernel: [206384.605899] [IPTABLES DROP] :IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.4.100 DST=74.125.226.80 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=15546 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=11288
Feb 12 17:15:20 LINUX-GATEWAY kernel: [206389.606038] [IPTABLES DROP] :IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.4.100 DST=74.125.226.80 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=15560 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=11289
Feb 12 17:15:25 LINUX-GATEWAY kernel: [206394.607171] [IPTABLES DROP] :IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.4.100 DST=74.125.226.80 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=15573 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=11290
Feb 12 17:15:30 LINUX-GATEWAY kernel: [206399.606336] [IPTABLES DROP] :IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.4.100 DST=74.125.226.80 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=15588 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=11291
Feb 12 17:15:35 LINUX-GATEWAY kernel: [206404.620397] [IPTABLES DROP] :IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.4.100 DST=74.125.226.80 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=15603 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=11292
```

So the ping packets from the lan client are being dropped in the forward chain (only chain with log_drop)

I cant figure out why .. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind. i figured it out. for anyone who might stumble upon this, below is my iptables setup with LOG chains for troubleshooting purposes.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  169 36504 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
  218 18804 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 4919  365K ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:domain dpts:1024:65535
  196 24001 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
10698  696K ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
   53  3686 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:telnet
   77  7709 LOG_DROP_INPUT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1258 75480 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth1   eth0    anywhere             anywhere
23927   31M ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth1    anywhere             anywhere
  195 12057 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
17512 1425K ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
  211 40089 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:telnet
   18  1860 LOG_DROP_FORWARD  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  457 61686 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
19715 4141K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOG_DROP (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
43246 2583K LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `[IPTABLES DROP] :'
43246 2583K DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOG_DROP_FORWARD (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   18  1860 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `[IPTABLES DROP FORWARD] : '
   18  1860 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOG_DROP_INPUT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   77  7709 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `[IPTABLES DROP INPUT] : '
   77  7709 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the output of "iptables -S"?  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're having problems, I would start by simplyfing your configuration.  Get rid of all the extraneous rules until you have a basic configuration working.  That is, start with:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

And make sure you have the necessary `sysctl` set:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

And now see if things work.  If they *do* work, slowly start making
changes.  If they *don't* work, let us know and we'll proceed from
there.

Comment: sounds like a good idea. let me do that and get back

Comment: @ larsks .. tried what you suggested. more into in update under my original post. thanks, ankit

Comment: Your configuration still looks substantially more complicated than what I have suggested.  There's no point in complicating your ruleset until you've established basic functionality.

Comment: followed your suggested and added logging capability along the way. its working now ! :). Have posted mine as an answer. it might look a bit complicated but its logical.